# Wrapping C++ Dynamic Arrays in Scripting Languages coded in C++

Tags: c++, scripting, stl, vector

I have a minimal scripting language (without arrays) built in C++ used as glue for Monte Carlo simulations. I make use of a library of wrapped c/c++ functions to extent my language, normally something like this:

```
extern "C" double myWrappedMathFunction(double argument){...}
```

Now, I would like add dynamic arrays and wrap some functions from the C++ STL Vector container. My idea is to construct STL vectors using function calls from my scripting language. All vectors would be of doubles. For example calling vecIni(vectorName) would create an empty (or some initial default dimension) vector named vectorName.

What would be the best way to construct these vectors in a scripting language coded in C++?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `std::vector` itself to represent the dynamic arrays. Probably you can add some syntax to represent array literals in the scripting language:

```
v1 = {3.4, 5.67} // an array initialized with two values.
v2 = {} // an empty array.
```

The above script should translate to the following C++ code:

```
std::vector<double> v1;
v1.push_back(3.4);
v1.push_back(5.67);

std::vector<double> v2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I was trying something more ambitious.  How can I make the function call from my scripting language declare v2 as a std::vector and possibly initializing it with some values? For example initializing an array with 10 values  `extern "C" void vecIni(vector<double> arg){
  for (int i=0; i<9; i++){arg[i]=0;}
};` calling vecIni(v2) will arise an out of scope error since obviously v2 was never declared before

Comment: @anton skvorts instead of the `{}` syntax introduce a type called `vector` and use it just the way you use other types like `string` and `double`.